# Wrap textNodes without separating on <br>?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to wrap text nodes while including `<br>` as part of the node, rather than splitting the nodes at each `<br>` I would like the nodes to still break up on block elements like `<p>`. ?

If I had an element

```
<div id=test>This is <br> a sentence.<p>This is <br> another.</p></div>
```

And I call

```
$('#test').contents().filter(function () {
return (this.nodeType == 3)
}).wrap('<span>');
```

This results in

```
<div id=test><span>This is</span> <br><span> a sentence.</span><p><span>This is</span><br><span> another</span></p></div>
```

My desired result would be

```
<div id=test><span>This is <br> a sentence.</span><p>This is <br> another.</p></div>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the actual end problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: I just would like to prevent the massive amount of redundant html tags. I have a WYSIWYG editor that adds tags using this method. 

When I valid the html using Simple html dom and htmlPurifier, the more tags in the content the longer the validation takes.

Comment: But why are you adding span tags in the first place?

Comment: I am not adding only span tags. I am adding an assortment of em, strong, u, strike, and span tags. I simply used span for simplicity sake in the example.

Comment: @user3591017  Question update changes Question from _"Wrap textNodes without separating on **<br>**?"_ ? At "My desired result would be" : `<div id=test><span>This is <br> a sentence.</span><p><span>This is <br> another.</span></p></div>` . What is logic that wraps `innerHTML` of `<p>` with `<span>` ?

Comment: Oh you're right. I should have proof-read. Fixed the mistake. Only the text outside the p should be wrapped.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a brute force way.  It traverses each direct child of `#test` and collects sequences of textNodes + br tags and when the sequence ends, it wraps what is has accumulated so far in a span.

```
function wrapPlainTextWithBR(selector) {
    var cum = [];
    function flush(pos) {
        if (cum.length) {
            var temp = document.createElement("span");
            $(pos).before(temp);
            var span = $("<span>").append(cum);
            $(temp).after(span);
            $(temp).remove();
            cum.length = 0;
        }
    }

    var items = $(selector).contents();
    items.each(function(index, element) {
        if (this.nodeType === 3 || (this.nodeType === 1 && this.tagName === "BR")) {
            cum.push(this);
            // if we just processed the last element, then flush now
            if (index === (items.length - 1)) {
                flush(this);
            }
        } else {
            // found non-text node, non-BR, flush any in the cum list
            flush(this);
        }
    });
}

wrapPlainTextWithBR("#test");
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/zgcaeszn/

---

**Edit:** I realized this can be simplified a bit by using jQuery's `.wrapAll()` like this:

```
function wrapPlainTextWithBR(selector) {
    var cum = [];
    function flush(pos) {
        if (cum.length) {
            $(cum).wrapAll("<span />");
            cum.length = 0;
        }
    }

    var items = $(selector).contents();
    items.each(function(index, element) {
        if (this.nodeType === 3 || (this.nodeType === 1 && this.tagName === "BR")) {
            cum.push(this);
            // if we just processed the last element, then flush now
            if (index === (items.length - 1)) {
                flush(this);
            }
        } else {
            // found non-text node, non-BR, flush any in the cum list
            flush(this);
        }
    });
}
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/wemwerjv/

Comment: @user3591017 - If by resource extensive you mean does it use a lot of memory - I would not think so as it is just moving DOM elements around.  It will trigger a reflow because of all the DOM manipulation.

Comment: @user3591017 - I added a slightly simplified version that takes advantage of jQuery's `.wrapAll()`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```js
$("#test").html(function(i, html) {
  var p = $.parseHTML(html).filter(function(el, i) {
      return el.tagName === "P" 
  });
  return $("<span />", {
           "html": $(this).contents().filter(function(idx, el) {
                     return el.nodeType === 3 
                            || el.tagName === "BR" 
                            || el.tagName !== "P"
                   })
         }).add(p)     
});

console.log($("#test")[0].outerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<div id=test>This is <br> a sentence.<p>This is <br> another.</p></div>
```

Comment: I tried with the new example and it removed the p. Is there a way to do this while keeping the paragraph?